# Is there a way to continuously display the system time on the Chrome browser panel?

Tags: google-chrome, systemtime

how can I have my system time to be displayed in chrome browser panel while working, I always keep my task bar on auto hide mode, every time I don't want to go down to check the time, is there any way to have it displayed in/on my browser and updating continuously.

I tried various options like searching for any gadget, extension or any option available within my system or chrome's settings but I didn't find. can someone help ?